# Google Firestore Data Modeling for Appointment Application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I'm currently developing a application with the aim to help doctors track their clients, inventory and appointments. For the data storage I use Firestore.

My current problem is the data modeling specifically regarding the appointment collection.

### Current Approach

There is **one top level collection** called 'users' where all user (or specifically 'doctors') documents are stored.

This top level collection has **three sub collections**: clients, products and appointments.

The 'clients' and 'products' collections consist of documents for each client or product, and also a snippet, so if the doctor opens the client overview in the application, only one document has to be read in order to provide him with the needed data. If the doctor wants to see the detailed client / product, the specific document gets loaded.

### **Now my problem:**

I have an appointment calendar in my application. So any appointments should be displayed there like in any other calendar app out there. Currently, every single appointment is stored in one separate document, so if the doctor opens up the calendar, all existing documents in this sub collection will be read.

I thought of using another snippet document here, which contains all the important information of all the appointments, so it is only one read needed. But then this document would also contain a ton of entries which are not even so important anymore, because the appointment was 1 year ago. Also, I could imagine that the document limits of firebase will be reached quite fast.

---

How to I split this up? How can I denormalize this the best way?
Should I create a snippet document for a specific time period using a cloud function, so there is like 1 document read for a monthly view of the calendar?

Comment: Hi @felixjiricka, [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) can achieve fetching only specific data. What's the objective on denormalization of the Firestore Data Structure. Do you want to lessen the billing charges from the reads and writes of documents?

Comment: What exactly in this structure doesn't work as you need? At a first glance, it looks good to me.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB yes I want to optimize to minimize the needed document reads. If I keep it like it is right now there is one document read for every appointment of a user, so if the user has 100 appointments stored and opens the calendar -> 100 more reads. Is it a good way to create these document snippets with the most important data of appointments for each month?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear how you decided to solve this.

Comment: @jbryanh I decided to create a snipped document for each month. Every time an appointment gets added, updated or removed a cloud function will update the corresponding snippet document. In the calendar view I only load the snippet, if a user clicks on a calendar entry it loads the full document.